# How to connect user between a front and an api by using login / password or Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

Here is I have a small problem of architecture, first of all, I have two applications:

- An api writes symfony 3.3
- A front writes too it symfony 3.3

Then, I would like have two manner to sign in:

- the first one by using of third application such as Facebook, Google or Twitter. For this part I thought of using hwiOauthBundle
- Or simply by login / password. Here I thought of using FOSUerbundle

Finally I would like to have secure api, that a not connected user cannot reach the resources of the api.

What do I have to install or to develop to have all the expressed criteria higher?

In advance, thank you of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup some kind of login proxy endpoint that has the oauth client_id and secret.

Then with the username and password given by the user you have to query the backend oauth token endpoint to get an accesss token.

After that you just need to sign your request to the backend with that token.

In my case I'm using FosUserBundle for user management, FosOauthServerBundle for the Open Auth management. Both are installed in the backend.

Once installed you have to register a aAuth client. This tutorial was really helpful for me [OAuth2 Explained](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/07/19/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-terminology/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, how do you register for a new user?
Likewise how do we "connect" a facebook user to our API?

Comment: With a custom grant type that checks the token generated by the Facebook login process. I use fosuserbundle to manage users ( create in this case) and the store the Facebook token linked to that user.